# Retrieve a object name in iteration

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I've got a file version.json:

```
{
 "components":{
   "toto": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-toto",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    },
    "tata": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-tata",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    },
    "titi": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-titi",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    }
 "versions": {
   "test-toto": "2.1",
   "test-tata": "2.2",
   "test-titi": "2.3"
   }
```

I've got a file version2.json:

```
{
 "components":{
   "toto": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-toto",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    },
    "tata": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-tata",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    },
    "titi": {
     "test": [
       {
         "name": "test-tata",
         "type": "html"
       }
      ]
    }
 "versions": {
   "test-toto": "1.1"
   "test-tata": "1.2",
   "test-titi": "2.3"
   }
```

I'm trying to create a JSON with this syntax:

```
 {
   components: "",
   newVersion: "",
   oldVersion: "",
 }
```

I want to push only the versions where the version is different with their name of component like this:

```
[{
   components: "toto",
   newVersion: "2.1",
   oldVersion: "1.1"
 },
 {
   components: "tata",
   newVersion: "2.2",
   oldVersion: "1.2",
 }
 ]
```

What I'm doing :

```
public async listDiffer(): Promise<any[]> {

    const showVersion = fs.readFileSync("versions.json", "utf8");
    const json1 = JSON.parse(showVersion);
    const list1 = json1.versions;

    const showVersion2 = fs.readFileSync("versions2.json", "utf8");
    const json2 = JSON.parse(showVersion2);
    const list2 = json2.versions;

    const diffList: Array<{ components: string; newVersion: string; oldVersion: string }> = [];

    const keysFromHead = Object.keys(list1);

        keysFromHead.forEach((key) => {
            if (list1[key] !== list2[key]) {
                diffList.push({
                    components: ,
                    newVersion: list1[key],
                    oldVersion: list2[key],
                });
            }
        });
    });
    return diffList;
}
```

What I have:

```
[{
   components: ,
   newVersion: "2.1",
   oldVersion: "1.1"
 },
 {
   components: ,
   newVersion: "2.2",
   oldVersion: "1.2",
 }
 ]
```

How can I retrieve the components name (toto and tata) 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1) Your JSON has syntax mistakes - you can check whats wrong and fix it :) ==> here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Thanks but it's just to give you some examples
It's not a problem about my JSON but how can I retrieve components

Comment: Please provide a clear and working example which has your issue on https://jsbin.com/?js,console

Answer (score 0):

```js
// get an array of objects from the values of l1.components
// keys and iterate over it using reduce with an initial value
// of an empty array
const result = Object.values(l1.components).reduce((acc, { test }) => {
  // if "test" is falsy it means that the current object is the "versions" object
  // so just return the acc
  if (!test) return acc

  const name = test[0].name
  const newVersion = l1.components.versions[name]
  const oldVersion = l2.components.versions[name]

  // compare the versions and if they are different
  // add the new object into the acc
  return newVersion === oldVersion
    ? acc
    : acc.concat({
        components: name.split('-')[1],
        newVersion,
        oldVersion,
      })
}, [])

console.log(result)
```